# Running a BackGroundWorker more than once

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if you can help?, please bear in mid I’m an absolute novice.

I trying to update a program I made a few years ago for booking in serial numbers into a CRM application.
Currently it runs the following command for each of the 100 textboxes and has worked a treat booking in more than 81000 serial numbers.

```
If TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then
Clipboard.SetText(TextBox1.Text)
RetBat1 = Shell("C:\Windows\BookIN.exe", , True)
Endif
```

The new version of the app I’ve added a listbox1 with the serial numbers in, I’m then running the below For Each loop.

The For Each loop copies each Item into the clipboard and the BookIN.exe tabs to the right location in the CRM and pastes the information, then clicks a button in the CRM for a new Line and then runs again. This works fine, but I want to add a stop button or a stop checkbox.

```
For Each items In ListBox1.Items
Clipboard.SetText(items)
RetBat1 = Shell("C:\Windows\BookIN.exe", , True)
Next
```

I have tried adding the Retbat1 to a backgroundworker, which checks if Checkbox1.checked then exit the for each loop.
The first serial number works, but when the backgroundworker runs more than once I get the following error.

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
Else
Dim RetBat1 As String
RetBat1 = Shell("C:\Windows\BookIN.exe", , True)
End If
```

System.InvalidOperationException: 'This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.'

Sorry if this makes not sense, thanks James

Comment: Yeah, not sure you’ve quite got your head around background workers.  https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567 is a pretty good guide I’ve referred to myself a number of times for years

Comment: OT: you ought to be using `Process.Start` rather than `Shell`.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I will definitely have a look at the guide. My idea behind using the background work, was because when I tried the click my stop button the app would stop responding, other than that it was all working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it would go is that you would run the `BackgroundWorker` and have your loop in the `DoWork` event handler and check whether a cancellation has been requested within that loop. As you've described it, you would then handle the `CheckedChanged` even of your `CheckBox` and request the cancellation when the event is raised. I would not use a `CheckBox` though, because that implies that you can uncheck it to uncancel the work. I would suggest using a `Button` and handling its `Click` event, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'We must get the data from the UI here and pass it into the background thread.
    Dim items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToArray()

    'Start the background work and pass in the data.
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(items)

    'Enable the Cancel button.
    Button2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Disable the Cancel button so it cannot used again.
    Button2.Enabled = False

    'Request that background processing be cancelled.
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'Get the data that was passed in.
    Dim items = DirectCast(e.Argument, String())

    'Process each item.
    For Each item In items
        'Check whether processing has been cancelled.
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            'Cancel processing.
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        'Process the current item here.
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        MessageBox.Show("The background operation was cancelled")
    Else
        'Disable the Cancel button.
        Button2.Enabled = False

        MessageBox.Show("The background operation completed successfully")
    End If
End Sub
```

The *Cancel* `Button` should be disabled by default and notice that this code ensures that it is only enabled when background processing is in progress. Note that the other `Button` probably ought to be disabled while the processing is in progress too. If you don't do that, at least check `IsBusy` on the `BackgroundWorker`. The visual feedback to the user is better though.

Comment: This works a treat, thanks for the tips for each section as it really helps me get my head around how it all works.
So it now running the “BookIn.exe” for each of the items in the listbox and the stop button doesn’t cause my app to stop responding.
 
I do have another quick question, which is I need to run a copy to clipboard command before the BookIn.exe runs. If I add a MsgBox(item) it works and displays a message box with the item name, however if I try to use the clipboard command it just displays the “The background operation completed successfully” message any ideas.

Comment: ‘Process the current item here.
 ‘works           
 MsgBox(item) 
‘ but if I replace with the below it doesn’t work and I get the completed message.
Clipboard.SetText(item) 
 Dim RetBat1 As String
RetBat1 = Shell("C:\Windows\BookIN.exe", , True)

Comment: The `Clipboard` class only works in an STA thread, which basically means that you can't use it in the `DoWork` event handler, just like a control. I read that in the documentation which is what you should have done when it didn't work as expected. I guess you could call `ReportProgress` and copy to the Clipboard in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.